# Infopath how to select the selected Index of a dropbox

Tags: sharepoint, drop-down-menu, indexing, infopath

There is absolutely nothing about this anywhere. So Just as well start one.

How can you select or get the selected index of a drop box (without code at the back) in infopath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field that the dropbox is bound to will contain the value of the item that is selected.  to change the item that is selected, change the value of the field.